# Activiti Timer Task email Task Reminder Notifications

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I need to send a task reminder email notification on each task in my workflow. Right now I am thinking to put Timer Task on each User Task and have a Service Task attached to it.

My question is, how can I get the candidate group of the User Task (Step 1) in the Send an Email Service Task?

[image]

Comment: use a process variable